# Which has greater authority to Mormons: Book of Mormon or the Bible?

Tags: bible, lds, book-of-mormon

The question says it all: Which book has more authority to Mormons - the book of Mormon or the Bible?

Comment: Please use the search bar next time before asking.

Comment: The Bible is of equal value to Mormons as the book of mormon as far as it is translated correctly. K